# XMLHttpRequest scripts conflict

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a conflict with these two scripts that I do not know how to solve. When I add xhook.js the playerhtml5 script stops working.

I made some tests and changed `XMLHTTP = 'XMLHttpRequest';` for something like `XMLHTTP = 'XMLHttpRequest2';` in xhook.js playerhtml5 returns to work but xhook.js stops working

https://jpillora.com/xhook/dist/xhook.js

https://static-egc.xvideos-cdn.com/v-d4b92c5105a/v3/js/skins/min/player.html5hls.static.js

The error that occurs

```
 ERROR: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null" in player.html5hls.static.js
    window.onerror @ player.html5hls.static.js
    error (async)
    o @ player.html5hls.static.js
    (anonymous) @ player.html5hls.static.js
    (anonymous) @ player.html5hls.static.js
    player.html5hls.static.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null
        at e.readystatechange (player.html5hls.static.js)
        at Object.EventEmitter.emitter.(anonymous function) [as dispatchEvent] (xhook.js:169:22)
        at emitReadyState (xhook.js:382)
        at setReadyState (xhook.js:405)
        at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (xhook.js:438)
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is a built in object. If you add a `2` to the end, the script will no longer reference it but `null`. Which causes the error. You're asking "how can I use X to do Y?", but you should be asking "how can I do X?" What are you trying to do? What do you need xhook for?

Comment: I need xhook to intercept XMLHttpRequest requests and change it. It works well for this. But this conflicting with the player.html5hls.static.js and I do not know the reason. I just need both of them to work together or to know why they can not work together.